# Extract a JSON property using LINQ

Tags: c#, json, linq, .net-core

I have a json object as the following:

```
{
    "search-results": {
        "results-count": "2"
        "entry": [
            {
                "id": "0",
                "count": "10",
            },
            {
                "id": "1",
                "count": "22",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to get the sum of `count`s; `32` in this example. I am looking into doing this using LINQ, but any more "readable" alternative would be appreciate.

Comment: Just like a simple linq query like searchresults.entry.Sum(i => i.count); ?

Comment: cannot get anything like that working, any code example?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add your LINQ as well to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var json = @"{
        'search-results': {
                    'results-count': '2',
                    'entry': [
                    {
                        'id': 0,
                        'count': 10,
                    },
                    {
                        'id': 1,
                        'count': 22,
                    }
            ]
        }
    }";


JObject searchResult = JObject.Parse(json);
int sum = (from entry in searchResult["search-results"]["entry"]
            select (int)entry["count"]).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with Linq. For example,

```
var jobject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var result = jobject["search-results"]["entry"].Sum(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x["count"]));
```